# Could not load type 'Microsoft.VisualBasic.PowerPacks.OvalShape' from 'Microsoft.VisualBasic.PowerPacks.Vs - ClickOnce

Tags: .net, clickonce

I am wondering if someone can point me in the right direction to solving this problem. I have an application that uses Click Once to deploy. When I try deploying it on an older Windows XP machine, I get the following error.

> System Update Required. Unable to install or run the application. The application requires that
>    assembly Microsoft.VisualBasic.PowerPacks.Vs Version 10.0.0.0 be installed in the Global  Assembly Cache (GAC) First.

When I look at the GAC on that machine (C:\Windows\Assemblies), I see "Microsoft.VisualBasic.PowerPacks.Vs", along with 10.0.0.0 in the version column. Furthermore, when I right click on that assembly, I get the option to uninstall it. (which implies it is already installed, making the error above worthless)

In the Prerequisites dialog for the project, the "Microsoft Visual Basic PowerPacks 10.0" is marked as a prerequisite. Also, the option for "Download prerequisites from component vendor's web site." is selected. If the installer does not think the Power Pack is installed, why does it not go and download it?

Does anyone know what the real issue is at hand here?

Thanks

Comment: Are you targeting .NET 4.0?  The GAC is not in c:\windows\assemblies anymore.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using any of item from Visual Basic Power pack (e.g line. rectangle etc..), you need to add a reference to VB Power pack, and copy the reference to local.

A detailed guide is shown [here](http://ntcoder.com/bab/2013/12/20/visualbasic-powerpack-missing-from-visual-studio-2013/).